# PHP simple html dom parser. Empty span

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse the site with folowing code.

```
<span id="ctl00_cphBody_resList_pnlResumes_rptResumes_ctl01_Label1" class="address">Somename, <nobr>Someage</nobr></span>
```

I'm parsing it this way

```
$fio=$text_specialty_next->find('span#ctl00_cphBody_resList_pnlResumes_rptResumes_ct'.$n.'_Label1');
```

But when I'm trying to print the result,

```
echo $fio->innertext;
```

There result is empty. What can cause this problem?

Comment: Now my sollution is like this.
if ($n<10)
      {
       $nstr="0".$n;
       $fio=$text_specialty_next->find('span[id=ctl00_cphBody_resList_pnlResumes_rptResumes_ctl'.$nstr.'_Label1]');      
      }
      else
      {
       $fio=$text_specialty_next->find('span[id=ctl00_cphBody_resList_pnlResumes_rptResumes_ctl'.$n.'_Label1]');
      }
where $n=01, and it's increased.

Comment: I've fixed mistakes, and changed span#value to span[id=value], but it still doesn't work.=( What can I do now?

Answer (score 2):

in `find()`

`rptResumes_ct'.$n.'_Label1'`

but it should be

`rptResumes_ctl'.$n.'_Label1'`

You miss an "l"

And what is the value of `$n` ?

Comment: Oh, it's "l". I thought it was 1, lol. $n it's a variable, it has a value, that I substitute. Than's I'll try to fix solution.

Comment: :)) yes `$n` is a variable . I mean, what is it's value, how you use this ?

Comment: The value is 01 and it's increased in the loop. By the way, is it possible to make '01' value (not '1')?

Comment: @SergeyScopin , you can use `sprintf()` while declaring `$n` . Like this : `$n = sprintf("%02d", 1);` => `$n = 01`

Answer (score 1):

Does `$n="l01"`? What parser are you using? In [SimpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) you need to use `find(span[id=...]);`

Comment: In the [simpleHTMLDom Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) it says to use element[attribute=value]. I am presuming you are using simpleHTMLDom. You also need to check the search string as @Eray says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. $find->smth returns array, whick doesn't have innertext of course. I have to use foreach(find->smth as $someelement) to echo it.